# Pagination navigation is not working inside iframe

Tags: laravel, iframe, pagination

In this website everything is working fine,
but when we load the website in a iframe then the everything is working but the pagination is not working.

Main Website: https://dropflo.thrivedeskdocs.com/en

Inside Iframe: https://iframetester.com/?url=https://dropflo.thrivedeskdocs.com/en

Recreate the issue: Go to the iframetester url, then go to "Getting started page" then scroll down to bottom, click page no 2. The page will not change.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be an issue with your URL generation.
The URL in your pagination links uses http instead of https.

Be sure to set your APP_URL .env variable to the correct URL, with the correct scheme:

```
// .env
APP_URL=https://dropflo.thrivedeskdocs.com
```

If that alone does not work (though it should, after clearing your configuration cache) try adding the following line to your AppServiceProvider:

```
\URL::forceSchema('https');
```

It may be a good idea to set it inside a conditional so that it only runs on certain environments. Maybe something like this:

```
if (parse_url(config('app.url', 'http://localhost'), PHP_URL_SCHEME) == 'https') {
    \URL::forceSchema('https');
}
```

On a related note, you should also make your page automatically redirect any http requests to the https version of the same request.

https://growhackscale.com/blog/301-redirect-http-https